# JQuery hide does not remove the space of the object?

Tags: jquery

I am using some jQuery code where I hide a list item...

```
 $("ul.items").each(function() {
    $("li:gt(4)", this).hide();
```

My problem is that `.hide` seems to hide the element but the space for it is still allocated.

Is there a way to remove this space... like `display:none` on CSS does?

UPDATE: `.hide` is actually taking away the element but the other elements are not stretching up to take the missing space left by the element.

Comment: Which space? Show the HTML code.

Comment: can you paste the source code may be in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm that shouldn't happen. `$.fn.hide()` sets `display: none;` not `visibility: hidden;` or `opacity: 0;` (which would hide the element but keep its space occupied).

"This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none'), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value" - from http://api.jquery.com/hide/.

Edit: Have you checked with Firebug (or similar) what actually happens to the element?

Answer (score 3):

You must also hide/show every html space after each element. I encountered this same challenge and after going through comments above helped resolved the issue. In my case, I separated the elements with `<br>` so even after hiding, these `<br>` are not hidden. My case as follows:

html

```
<article> ... </article><br>
<article> ... </article><br>
<article> ... </article><br>  // etc.
```

jquery:

```
$(ele).on('keyup', function() {
    var articles = $('main').find('article');
    var articles_le = articles.length;
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<articles_le; i++) {
        article = articles.eq(i);
        if ($(compare)) {
            article.show();
            article.next().show();
        } else {
            article.hide();
            article.next().hide();
        }
    }
});
```

This effectively removes spaces created by `<br>`

Comment: Thanks, it's funny when you realize it's such an obvious oversight :)