# Jquery .hide() does not totally remove the spaces

Tags: jquery

```
function CondtionalCheck(BaseControlID, ChildControlID, Condition) {

    if ($("#" + BaseControlID).is(':checked')) {
        $("#div" + ChildControlID).show();
    } else {
        $("#div" + ChildControlID).hide();
        $("#" + ChildControlID).val("");
    }
}
```

Above is my `hide()` and `show()` function. After the element is hide, it does remove the spaces, but it does not really removing all the spaces.

What causes this to happen?

Comment: Include the HTML with your jQuery as a [mcve]

Comment: please look at this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627250/jquery-hide-does-not-remove-the-space-of-the-object....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050880/hiding-elements-using-jquery-taking-up-space-on-page

Comment: as zer00ne said please add your HTML also because with only jquery we can't help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods `show()` and `hide()` set the visibility of an element. If you want to completely hide the DOM element, then it's better to use the method `css()`.
Your code will look like this:

```
function CondtionalCheck(BaseControlID, ChildControlID, Condition) {
  if ($("#" + BaseControlID).is(':checked')) {
      $("#div" + ChildControlID).css('display', 'block');
  } else {
      $("#div" + ChildControlID).css('display', 'none');
      $("#" + ChildControlID).val("");
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this as well...but still not working... it got help to reduce the spaces, but there is spaces...it does really remove all the spaces

Comment: @ellie Means these spaces refer not to the element that you want to hide, but to the neighboring ones. If you show the html and css code, then it can be possible to understand

Comment: Was it like that in older versions of JQuery? Because now [hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) is roughly equivalent to calling `.css( "display", "none" )`, except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value.

Answer (score 0):

The `hide()` function will set the style of a DOM element as `visibility: hidden`. It's equivalent to saying `myElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';` in regular, non jQuery javascript.

But a hidden element is still incorporated into the "flow" (or layout) of a page, as you are clearly seeing. What you need to set is [the `display` CSS property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp). I'm not sure what the jQuery function would be, but in regular javascript it's `myElement.style.display = 'none';`. This will actually remove your element from the "flow" (or layout) of the webpage.